# Graphite's carbon-cache.py cache flush interval?

Tags: graphite

I checked the docs and conf files, but I don't see any mention of how Graphite's carbon-cache.py decides when to flush its in-RAM cache. How often does this happen, and can I control it?

Answer (score 0):

The [Graphite Project documentation on carbon.conf](https://graphite.readthedocs.io/en/stable/config-carbon.html#carbon-conf) does not cover the settings that effect write operations.
However, the [`carbon.conf.example`](https://github.com/graphite-project/carbon/blob/master/conf/carbon.conf.example#L59-L64) on GitHub, as well as this chapter in the [O'reilly book Monitoring with Graphite](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/monitoring-with-graphite/9781491916421/ch04.html) cover the `MAX_UPDATES_PER_SECOND` setting.

> Limits the number of whisper update_many() calls per second, which effectively
> means the number of write requests sent to the disk. This is intended to
> prevent over-utilizing the disk and thus starving the rest of the system.
> When the rate of required updates exceeds this, then carbon's caching will
> take effect and increase the overall throughput accordingly.

Filesystem and block storage settings for write-back and write-through will also be a factor in how much is cached in memory and when it is written out to block storage.  You can also call [sync](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sync.2.html) to force cache write to disk.